# Image Magick: dimmed caption with border

Tags: imagemagick

I am using Image Magick to overlay a dimmed caption to an image, with IM automatically choosing the best fontsize:

```
convert -background '#0008' -fill white -geometry +0+330 -size 370x60 caption:$title $image +swap -composite $imageOutput
```

My problem is that there is not enough space around the text, I would like to add some "padding". I usually do that with the -border option but if I add this to my command above, the caption is not dimmed anymore.

Do you have a solution to create a dimmed caption with enough room around the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution, but it's a bit of a kludge because I had trouble extending or bordering a semi-transparent background. In the end, I just constructed the caption on a black background and bordered it in black, then I tweaked the alpha channel afterwards:

```
convert -background black -bordercolor black -fill white \
   -size 370x60 caption:"This is the title"              \
   -trim -border 20 -channel A -fx '(lightness/2)+.5'    \
   -geometry +0+200 background.gif +swap -composite result.png
```

[image]

The only tricky part is `-channel A -fx ...`. The first part means that we are only affecting/modifying the alpha/opacity channel. The `0.5` means that all pixels become at least 50% opaque, and `(lightness/2)` means that absolutely white pixels, i.e. your lettering, (which will have a lightness of 1) become fully opaque because `0.5+(1/2)` totals to one. The point of this is to preserve the anti-aliasing around the edges of the letters to some degree.

Comment: Wow incredible, the lettering becoming transparent is what was preventing me from using this solution.

Comment: Just wrap the fx in a ternary, and it'l keep the lettering from becoming transparent. `-channel A -fx 'u==1?(lightness/2)+.5:u'`